# How to get keyboard input in D?

Tags: input, keyboard, d

How does one get keyboard input in D? Do you have to use standard C functions, or is there a D way to do it?

Edit: By this I mean get events on keypresses, like when the user presses ESC, not just textual input from stdin.

Comment: What OS are you on and what kind of app are you building? Command-line tool? GUI-based?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use standard C functions.

Though if you are using a GUI library there may be key events you can bind to.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to be using SDL in this project anyway, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it earlier.

Answer (score 5):

`stdin` is a global variable in `std.stdio`. It is a `std.stdio.File`. So, pretty much any operations that you can do on a `File` which is opened only for reading, you can do on `stdin`. The two functions that you're most likely to be interested in are `readln()` and `readf()` (both of which can be called without explicitly using `stdin`, and `readf()` is actually unique to `stdin` rather than being part of `File`, so you *can't* use `stdin` with it explicitly). `readln()` reads in a line from `stdin`. `readf()` allows you to read in formatted input (similar to `scanf()` in C). This program:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    write("> ");
    auto input = strip(stdin.readln());
    writeln(input);

    write("> ");
    float f;
    readf("%f", &f);
    writeln(f);
}
```

could result in the following:

> > hello world
>   hello world
>   > 2.7
>   2.7

So, it's pretty straightforward. Personally, I'd most likely use `readln()` and then parse the resulting string if need be (likely with `std.conv.parse()`) rather than using `readf()`, but `readf()` obviously has its uses as well.

If you're looking for events from key presses rather than just textual input, I'm pretty sure that you're going to have to call an external libary for that (presumably one written in C). After all, to do that in C or C++, don't you already have to use a library such as ncurses? That being the case, D certainly isn't going to have anything to do that in the standard library. That's OS-specific. I suppose that someone could write a D wrapper around ncurses (and maybe even a wrapper which was cross-platform), but there's no such thing in the standard library. D's I/O functionality is built on top of standard C I/O, so while it does improve on it, it tends to be restricted in ways similar to the ways that standard C and C++ are restricted.

Comment: Downvote? What did I say wrong? If you don't tell me, I won't know, and can't improve.

Comment: Definitely upvote to oppose someone downvoted in silence. Wish someday SO requires comment if someone is giving downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Reads stdin and writes it to stdout.
import std.stdio;

int main()
{
    char[] buf;
    while (stdin.readln(buf))
        write(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

[Source](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html). Hope this helps!